# How do we recover if an application deletes all records in a mongodb and corresponding replicates?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to understand what to do in a worst case scenario that an application that connects to mongod somehow deletes or pollutes records and correspondingly the records of real time replicas.

Do admins usually keep a time phased (Weekly backup) of the database or is there a log that can used to restore the database to the point where things went awry?

In the event that a time based backup is used how would one recover the slice of the database that is created / deleted / updated from the point in time when the time based backup is made to the point in time when something went wrong?  For example the cloud manager from mongo inc says that it continuously records the replicate set oplog for say the past 24 hours, but is it possible to do this manually?  For example make a git like versioned set containing the last 24 hours of oplog entries that are committed every N writes?

Comment: Where I worked we did a mongodump everyday. Saved our hinds a couple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience the most common solution is like you said to keep a time based backup and worst case scenario revert to the latest backup when everything is lost.